# Problema con Menu Slider Bar

Tags: jquery

Hola a todos tengo un inconveniente, tengo un menú que al hacerse responsivo no logro hacer que al darle click a sus enlaces se vuelva a plegar el menú y la página se deslice hasta la opción seleccionada como cuando lo hace en modo escritorio. Dejo el código por si alguien se anima a dame una mano. Saludos

```
         <nav class="site-navigation text-right" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-md-0 mr-auto py-3"><a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-white"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>

              <ul class="site-menu js-clone-nav d-none d-lg-block">
                <li class="active">
                  <a class="js-scroll-trigger"  href="jofret.com">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#contactenos">Contáctenos</a></li>
                <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#productos">Productos</a></li>
                <!--li class="has-children">
                  <a href="#">Productos</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown arrow-top">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li-->
                <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Dejaré tambien todo el codigo js

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 "use strict";

 

 var siteMenuClone = function() {

  $('.js-clone-nav').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.clone().attr('class', 'site-nav-wrap').appendTo('.site-mobile-menu-body');
  });


  setTimeout(function() {
   
   var counter = 0;
      $('.site-mobile-menu .has-children').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        
        $this.prepend('<span class="arrow-collapse collapsed">');

        $this.find('.arrow-collapse').attr({
          'data-toggle' : 'collapse',
          'data-target' : '#collapseItem' + counter,
        });

        $this.find('> ul').attr({
          'class' : 'collapse',
          'id' : 'collapseItem' + counter,
        });

        counter++;

      });

    }, 1000);

  $('body').on('click', '.arrow-collapse', function(e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ( $this.closest('li').find('.collapse').hasClass('show') ) {
        $this.removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $this.addClass('active');
      }
      e.preventDefault();  
      
    });

  $(window).resize(function() {
   var $this = $(this),
    w = $this.width();

   if ( w > 768 ) {
    if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas-menu') ) {
     $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu');
    }
   }
  })

  $('body').on('click', '.js-menu-toggle', function(e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   e.preventDefault();

   if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas-menu') ) {
    $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu');
    $this.removeClass('active');
   } else {
    $('body').addClass('offcanvas-menu');
    $this.addClass('active');
   }
  }) 

  // click outisde offcanvas
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
     var container = $(".site-mobile-menu");
     if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
       if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas-menu') ) {
     $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu');
    }
     }
  });

 }; 
 siteMenuClone();


 var sitePlusMinus = function() {
  $('.js-btn-minus').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if ( $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val() != 0  ) {
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) - 1);
   } else {
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt(0));
   }
  });
  $('.js-btn-plus').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) + 1);
  });
 };
 // sitePlusMinus();


 var siteSliderRange = function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
 };
 // siteSliderRange();


 var siteMagnificPopup = function() {
  $('.image-popup').magnificPopup({
     type: 'image',
     closeOnContentClick: true,
     closeBtnInside: false,
     fixedContentPos: true,
     mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
      gallery: {
       enabled: true,
       navigateByImgClick: true,
       preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
     },
     image: {
       verticalFit: true
     },
     zoom: {
       enabled: true,
       duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
     }
   });

   $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
     disableOn: 700,
     type: 'iframe',
     mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
     removalDelay: 160,
     preloader: false,

     fixedContentPos: false
   });
 };
 siteMagnificPopup();


 /*var siteCarousel = function () {
  if ( $('.nonloop-block-13').length > 0 ) {
   $('.nonloop-block-13').owlCarousel({
      center: false,
      items: 1,
      loop: false,
    stagePadding: 0,
      margin: 20,
      nav: true,
    navText: ['<span class="icon-arrow_back">', '<span class="icon-arrow_forward">'],
      responsive:{
         600:{
          margin: 0,
          stagePadding: 10,
           items: 2
         },
         1000:{
          margin: 0,
          stagePadding: 0,
           items: 2
         },
         1200:{
          margin: 0,
          stagePadding: 0,
           items: 3
         }
      }
   });
  }

  $('.nonloop-block-13').owlCarousel({
     center: false,
     items: 1,
     loop: true,
     autoplay: true,
   stagePadding: 0,
     margin: 20,
     nav: true,
   navText: ['<span class="icon-arrow_back">', '<span class="icon-arrow_forward">'],
     responsive:{
        600:{
         margin: 0,
         stagePadding: 0,
          items: 2
        },
        1000:{
         margin: 0,
         stagePadding: 0,
          items: 2
        },
        1200:{
         margin: 0,
         stagePadding: 0,
          items: 3
        }
     }
  });

  if ( $('.slide-one-item').length > 0 ) {
   $('.slide-one-item').owlCarousel({
      center: false,
      items: 1,
      loop: true,
    stagePadding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      autoplay: true,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      nav: true,
      navText: ['<span class="icon-arrow_back">', '<span class="icon-arrow_forward">']
    });
   }
 };
 siteCarousel();
 */


 var siteStellar = function() {
  $(window).stellar({
     responsive: false,
     parallaxBackgrounds: true,
     parallaxElements: true,
     horizontalScrolling: false,
     hideDistantElements: false,
     scrollProperty: 'scroll'
   });
 };


 siteStellar();

 var siteCountDown = function() {

  if ( $('#date-countdown').length > 0 ) {
   $('#date-countdown').countdown('2020/10/10', function(event) {
     var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
       + '<span class="countdown-block"><span class="label">%w</span> weeks </span>'
       + '<span class="countdown-block"><span class="label">%d</span> days </span>'
       + '<span class="countdown-block"><span class="label">%H</span> hr </span>'
       + '<span class="countdown-block"><span class="label">%M</span> min </span>'
       + '<span class="countdown-block"><span class="label">%S</span> sec</span>'));
   });
  }
    
 };
 siteCountDown();

 var siteDatePicker = function() {

  if ( $('.datepicker').length > 0 ) {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  }

 };
 siteDatePicker();



  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 72)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.site-mobile-menu').collapse('hide');
  });

  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 75
  });

});
```

Como digo lo que necesito es que al hacer click cuando este en modo responsive sobre el enlace el slider bar se cierre y luego pueda hacer el scroll.

Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
$('.site-mobile-menu-body a').click(()=>{
    $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu')
})
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega más contexto a tu respuesta. Dónde deberia OP insertar ese código? Cómo funciona y por qué soluciona el problema de OP?

Comment: muchas gracias gmarsi me salvaste